# Get a string from a selenium element

Tags: node.js, selenium

Im using this :
`async function afterwait() {
  var y = String(await driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@id, 'executable_path')]")).getText())
  console.log(y)
}`

And here is what im trying to get into this var (Only the `C:\Program Files...`) :

`<td class="version" id="executable_path">C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe</td>`
It waits for a while without returning me anything. 
Without the async & await, it returns me "[object promise]"
Any idea about what's wrong ? :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
driver.findElement(By.id("executable_path")).getText()
```